# How to update UI data fetched by getServerSideProps in Nextjs

Tags: next.js

```
function Page({ data }) {
  // Render data...
  const itemList = data.items.map(item => {
    return <Item key = {item.id} />
  })
  return(
    <div>
      {itemList}
    </div>
  )
}

// This gets called on every request
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../data`)
  const data = await res.json()

  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { data } }
}

export default Page
```

I want to push a new item in the `data.items` array and update the UI.

Usually this can be achived by `useState()`, but in this case the data is fetched on the server side.

Is there an easy way to achive this?

Answer (score 0):

- Why don't you push the new item in the getServerSideProps and the send the final data as props? I did something like this:-

```js
import Axios from "axios";

const index = ({ data }) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {data.map(post => <li key={post.id}>
          {post.title}
        </li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const res = await Axios(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);
  const newPost = {
    userId: 10,
    id: 101,
    title: 'at nam consequatur ea labore ea harum',
    body: 'cupiditate quo est a modi nesciunt soluta\n' +
      'ipsa voluptas error itaque dicta in\n' +
      'autem qui minus magnam et distinctio eum\n' +
      'accusamus ratione error aut'
  }
  const data = [...res.data, newPost];
  return {
    props: {
      data
    }
  }
}

export default index;
```